# Distance between capitals

Tags: geography

What is the longest great circle distance between the capitals of two countries that share a land border?  The most common first answer I have heard comes in fourth.

Comment: The common (wrong) answer which comes to mind is Moscow and Beijing, right? ;)

Comment: @manetsus:  that is correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The distance between

> Paris (France) and Brasilia (Brasil) is 8730 km.

Yes, they do share a land border,

> because French Guiana is a proper département of France.

Comment: This was the expected answer.

Answer (score 11):

Google tells me that the distance between

> Moscow and Pyongyang is 6,408 km.

Comment: Yes, that beats Moscow-Beijing but loses to Paris-Brasilia and Paris-Parmaribo, Surinam.  Not many know that Russia borders North Korea.

Comment: This was a question on Jeopardy once, and their answer was Moscow-Pyongyang.

Answer (score 10):

Could be 15,970 km or 9,920 mi or so, between...

> ...Oslo, Norway, and Canberra, Australia.

Their countries share a border...

> ...in [Antarctica](http://www.24point0.com/ppt-shop/antarctica-map).

If touching at a single point counts, make that
17,660 km or 10,970 mi or so, between...

> ...Oslo, Norway, and Wellington, New Zealand.

Their countries touch...

> ...at the south pole.

If you care to
[dispute this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territorial_claims_in_Antarctica),
you're probably in the company of many earthlings,
but not many in those countries.

Comment: Well done.  I am in the company of the earthlings you mention, but am impressed nonetheless.

Comment: I care to dispute it! [Queen Maud Land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_Maud_Land) is not, strictly speaking, part of the country Norway. Rather, it's a dependent territory. Similarly, AAT is not part of Australia the country.

Answer (score 1):

Moscow to Washington? You can drive over the Bering straight at certain times of year which could qualify Russia and USA as sharing a border. Does this count?

Comment: No, that is the point of specifying a land border.

Comment: I understood that, I am querying if the Bering strait counts as a land border. I'm not too sure of the geography of that area of the world but have heard anecdotes of people covering it by car

Comment: As I see it, frozen water is not land, so even if you can cover it by car it is still a sea border.  If there were an island shared by the US and Russia, it would count, but I am not aware of one.